# How to calculate and used memory of multiple instance of a single process using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I have following result while running below powershell command,

```
PS C:\> Get-Process svchost

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    546      34    18528      14884   136    49.76    260 svchost
    357      14     4856       4396    47    18.05    600 svchost
    314      17     6088       5388    42    12.62    676 svchost
    329      17    10044       8780    50    12.98    764 svchost
   1515      49    36104      38980   454   232.04    812 svchost
    301      33     9736       6428    54     2.90    832 svchost
    328      26     8844       9744    52     4.32    856 svchost
    247      18     8144       9912    77    37.50    904 svchost
     46       5     1504        968    14     0.02   1512 svchost
    278      15     4048       5660    43     3.88   2148 svchost
     98      14     2536       2460    35     0.66   2504 svchost
```

Here im trying to calculte the total memory size `PM(K)` of process(s).i've following line in my ps1 script file

```
get-process svchost | foreach {$mem=("{0:N2}MB " -f ($_.pm/1mb))}
```

It gives the output in the following format

```
17.58MB 4.79MB 6.05MB 9.99MB 35.29MB 9.56MB 8.64MB 7.95MB 1.47MB 3.95MB 2.48MB
```

but i need total size as a single value like `107.75MB`

How to calculate the total used memory size of `svchost` process ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Measure-Object cmdlet

```
$measure = Get-Process svchost | Measure-Object PM -Sum
$mem = ("{0:N2}MB " -f ($measure.sum / 1mb))
```

Comment: Works nice, Nandri @user867377

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can calculate the total size of the entire collection using the += syntax

```
$mem = 0
Get-Process svchost | %{$mem += $_.pm}
"{0:N2}MB " -f ($mem/1mb)
```